# CDK Lambda NodejsFunction pdfmake Types

Tags: aws-lambda, pdfmake

How can I get pdfmake **types** working in an AWS CDK NodejsFunction Lambda?

For example, I'd like VSCode to highlight invalid properties and show intelliSense on objects.

```
// I'd like to type the doc definition like this:
const definition: TDocumentDefinitions = { ...

// And type the styles definition like this:
const styles: StyleDictionary = { ...

// Also, if I add styles to the docDefinition I get a type error that I have to tell typescript to ignore with @ts-ignore:
// Error: Argument of type '{ content: never[]; styles: { p: { margin: number[]; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TDocumentDefinitions'.
const styles = {
    p: { margin: [0, 0] }
};
const docDefinition = {
    content: [],
    styles
}
printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition)
```

The following pdfmake code below works but is not typed!

AWS CDK code:

```
new lambdaNJS.NodejsFunction(this, 'MyLambdaFunction', {
    ...
    bundling: {
        ...
        nodeModules: ['pdfmake'], //  List of modules that should NOT be bundled but instead included in the node_modules folder.
    }
});
```

Lambda Typescript code:

```
import PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');

const fonts = {
    Courier: {
        normal: 'Courier',
        bold: 'Courier-Bold',
        italics: 'Courier-Oblique',
        bolditalics: 'Courier-BoldOblique'
    },
    Helvetica: {
        normal: 'Helvetica',
        bold: 'Helvetica-Bold',
        italics: 'Helvetica-Oblique',
        bolditalics: 'Helvetica-BoldOblique'
    },
    Times: {
        normal: 'Times-Roman',
        bold: 'Times-Bold',
        italics: 'Times-Italic',
        bolditalics: 'Times-BoldItalic'
    },
    Symbol: {
        normal: 'Symbol'
    },
    ZapfDingbats: {
        normal: 'ZapfDingbats'
    }
};

const docDefinition = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph'
    ],
    defaultStyle: {
        font: 'Helvetica'
    }
};

const printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);
const doc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition);
doc.end();
```

My package.json contains: @types/pdfmake

There's a GitHub post here https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/525 where someone was able to get types working like this. But it's not clear what environment they are running or if this is in nodejs or browser.

```
import { StyleDictionary } from 'pdfmake/interfaces';

const styles: StyleDictionary = {
    ...
};
```

The following compiles in my VSCode but when deployed to Lambda results in a pdfmake/interfaces not found error.

```
import pdfmakeInterfaces = require('pdfmake/interfaces');

const definition: pdfmakeInterfaces.TDocumentDefinitions = {
    ...
}
```

The pdfmake index.d.ts file uses types and exports the main PdfPrinter object but doesn't export any types.

```
// Type definitions for pdfmake 0.1
// Project: http://pdfmake.org
// Definitions by: Milen Stefanov <https://github.com/m1llen1um>
//                 Rajab Shakirov <https://github.com/radziksh>
//                 Enzo Volkmann <https://github.com/evolkmann>
//                 Andi Pätzold <https://github.com/andipaetzold>
//                 Neal Mummau <https://github.com/nmummau>
//                 Jean-Raphaël Matte <https://github.com/jeralm>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
// TypeScript Version: 3.0

/// <reference types="pdfkit" />

import { BufferOptions, TDocumentDefinitions, TFontDictionary } from './interfaces';

declare class PdfPrinter {
    constructor(fontDescriptors: TFontDictionary);
    createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition: TDocumentDefinitions, options?: BufferOptions): PDFKit.PDFDocument;
}

export = PdfPrinter;
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about the expected behavior and the actual one are / the errors that you get ?

Comment: The beginning of the question has been updated for clarity.